NextJS Server Actions usage in NextJS API endpoints - concurrent or not?
As I learned by doing: NextJS Server Actions are synchronous.
I want to achieve concurrency; and I like the syntax of having this abstracted; therefore I've created a NextJS API endpoint that has the following syntax:
import { handleError } form '@/lib/utils';
import { z } from 'zod';

const schema = z.object({ .. }); // some random unrelated zod schema

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const myArgs = schema.parse(await req.json());

    const data = await myServerAction(myArgs);

    return Response.json({ data }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return handleError(error, req);
  }

However, I'm not entirely positive this runs concurrently.
Is there anybody that can confidently say/prove that this is indeed concurrent and not synchronous as the Server Actions are?

There is nothing in this code that will make it concurrent. Are you using any workers in myServerAction? Any external API? If not, then it shouldn't be concurrent.

Just a regular nextjs server action https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations

Even though there is no documentation on this anywhere, I have tested this many times and the answer is here

Code:
// api/relevant-chapters/route.ts
import { myServerAction } from '../actions.ts';
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const result = await myServerAction();
  return Response.json({data: result});
}

// actions.ts
'use server';
export const myServerAction = async () => {
  return await someAsyncQuery();
};

Conclusion: Yes this runs concurrently when you import server actions in API route handlers.
